# How to improve speed of an Angular 6.0 application

Tags: angular, performance, angular6, pagespeed

[image]
We have a brand new application built on angular 6, served by an apache 2.4.

We setup a local "prerender" instance to make the website to be crawled by search engines, we tried Angular Universal, but we had so many issues with libraries compatibily that we decided to swith to the prerender solution.

Then we added the google analytcs tracking code, and after a few days of data collection, we run the google PageSpeed Insights tool.

This is the PageSpeed Insights score that we received:

[image]
[image]

The Optimization Suggestions received by the PageSpeed Insights tool are:

- **Reduce server response time**: according to google, the page is served
  in about 3 seconds, but I guess most of the time is spent in the
  prerendering (call to local prerender instance). The obvious solution
  here is to cache the prerendered page, but I appreciate any other
  suggestion.
- **Enable compression**: according to google, the styles files (*.css) are
  not compressed. How to activate compression? I think some kind of
  filter on Apache should do the job. Has anyone a good configuration
  for this?
- **Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold
  content**: the report says: "None of the above-the-fold content on your
  page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to
  load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or
  inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the
  HTML." The blocking resources are .css and fonts, so I don't really
  know how to improve on this point. Any suggestion?
- **Leverage browser caching**: the reports says that images files (.png,
  .svg, etc..) are cacheable but "expiration not specified". Again, I
  guess I need to add some kind of filter on Apache, but I'm always scared of what happen when we release a new version of the angular application: any good configuration for this?

We also tested the site speed using https://tools.pingdom.com and this is the result:

[image]
The suggested optimizations are:

- **Specify a Vary: Accept-Encoding header**: Here the solution should be
  to configure apache to add the Header Vary: Accept-Encoding to the
  response. From what I know about the Vary header, it allow the
  caches, CDN ot other servers in the middle to serve different cached
  versions of the resource depeding on the browser requested a GZIP
  encoding or not. Is anyone aware of any side effects that this header
  can have, for instance when a new version of our angular application
  is released?
- **Combine external JavaScript**: a few js are for external tracking
  tools, so there is nothing we can do here, but 3 javascript are
  served by our angular application ( main.xxx.js, polyfills.xxx.js,
  runtime.xxx.js). How to combine theme in single js?

Comment: for compression you have to activate Gzip on your server that will help , and try to use lazyLoading pattern in your angular application to make loading faster, loading a module only when one of its route is called and build your app in AOT mode to get small app size and faster rendering on the browser

Comment: @FatehMohamed Thank you for the suggestion on lazy loading the modules, but at the moment the app is very simple. I forgot to mention that the application is build with the --prod flag that, according to documentation, compiles with AOT by default.

Answer (score 3):

After some time, we optimized a bit the application; here is what we optimized so far, I hope it can be useful to others.

**Enable compression**: 
After some investigation, this is the configuration that we added in the `.htaccess` of the angular application to setting up the gzip compression for HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html and https://gtmetrix.com/enable-gzip-compression.html for further reference.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

**Leverage browser caching**: 
Because we are building the angular application using `ng build --prod` , the application is packaged using the cache busting: files are name like `runtime.06daa30a2963fa413676.js` and we can use a pretty far Expires header on the static resources
This is the configuration added to `.htaccess`, that uses mod_expires to add a nice Expires header to the HTTP Response

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 6 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 6 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 6 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 6 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access 6 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 6 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 6 month"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```